# Non-blind Image Deconvolution GLSL

Tags: opengl, image-processing, glsl, convolution

Knowing a kernel with which an image has been convolved, is there a way to perform  image deconvolution in GLSL?

Comment: Sharpen filter http://r3dux.org/2011/06/glsl-image-processing/

Comment: @JAre Thank you for the comment. However that is not what I'm looking for. I need a deconvolution for a given blur kernel, not necessarily a generic sharpen filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Wiener Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter).
it will be hard to be done on the spatial domain.

Yet, I guess you have DFT (FFT) function in GLSL.
Once you convert to the DFT domain, all you need to do is multiplication, division and addition of item by item.
At the end, just do the Inverse DFT.